# What Are Some Interesting Questions That Could Be Used in a Blog Article To Help Promote The Site?

Tags: discussion, promotion, blogging

**UPDATE on May 12, 2012:**

I wanted to bump this question up to the top of the list with an edit. This question contains a list of questions that we felt could seed blog articles written about those topics that could also help further promote this site.

If you choose to write a blog article featuring one of these or another question, be sure to get the link using the **link** hyperlink that appears below the question body. It contains a reference to your userid so that any clicks on that link count towards your [Announcer, Booster, and Publicist badges](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/175/34). It's great to be recognized for helping to drive more traffic onto the site!

The StackExchange Team wrote a [blog article describing how to share links](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/). This has some pictures that help clarify how to use this feature.

---

If we were to find a blogger who would be interested in using one of our most interesting questions as the subject for a blog post, which questions would be the most interesting and most likely to help promote PMSE?

The general idea is the blogger would pick one of our interesting questions, write an article on the subject, and link to the PMSE Question as a resource using the `link` element on the question.  If the blogger is a member of the PMSE site, he/she may be rewarded with the [Publicist, Booster, or Announcer Badges!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/)

Please submit one question per answer.  You may submit more than one answer, but limit your answers to one question per answer so each question can be voted on independently.

Comment: this is great -- who are the notable bloggers in the PM world?

Comment: @Jeff - We have two people here who are active in the blogging community.  Pawelbrodzinski has referred quite a bit of traffic to our site and is a public speaker, and Mark Phillips has been featured in eWeek and runs a blog for his company.  I know there are other people here who I missed, and I encourage volunteers who would like to pick topics here and blog about them.

Answer (score 8):

It's not a question, but I would recommend you mention that **PMPs can claim PDUs for time spent on the site.** I did, and I emailed PMI, and they verified it for me.

I wrote about it in [this blog post here](http://ashiqalibhai.com/easy-free-self-paced-pdus-yes-really/). If you know any PMPs, let them know; they will have a vested interest, like the rest of us, in the site's survival.

Comment: +1 - That's a very good selling point to try to get expert Project Managers to contribute to this site.  This was news to me.  Thanks for sharing!  This is a great example of the kinds of articles that will help promote this site.

Comment: Yeah, I was claiming some PDUs and then my eye fell upon the category. I emailed them to double-check; it's definitely a great selling point.

Comment: Do they have a list of Q&A sites that qualify?  I'm wondering if we could get a link to PMSE on there?  Do you think that's possible?

Comment: I don't know. I suspect I'm the first one who tried this. Why don't we both try it and see what happens?

Answer (score 4):

I believe project management in one-man, or similarly tiny, projects ([How do you "project manage" when you are the only developer?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/1339/how-do-you-project-manage-when-you-are-the-only-developer)) is a good example of post which can be used in context of a bigger post/article. Actually it is even a good pretext to write one as subject is pretty interesting and can be approached from different angles, depending on a type of a project one considers.

**UPDATE:** OK, here you are, the post: http://blog.brodzinski.com/2011/04/project-management-one-man-project.html. I used the question about [introducing PM role in the company](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/969/at-what-point-should-a-company-decide-to-introduce-a-project-manager-role) as well.

Comment: Just a tip, you should grab the link from the `link` element on the question so you can earn the Booster badge next.  http://pm.stackexchange.com/q/969/89 is the link you should use for the "Introducing PM role in the company" question.

Comment: Actually I don't think I'd direct enough traffic to earn booster badge, but thanks for a tip - I updated links.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure, Pawel... I do share lots of links you post :)

Answer (score 2):

This question [How to Avoid Micro-Managing a Software Development Team?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/452/34), is our most highly-linked question so far.

**Advantage:**  It's an important topic for any project manager working with people.

**Disadvantage:** There is already a lot of information on the Internet about managing people, avoiding micro-managing them, and dealing with micro-managing bosses.

To make this work, the blogger would need to add an interesting twist to keep it from becoming similar to other noise on the Internet.

Answer (score 2):

This question, [When a PM goes on holiday, what can they expect when they get back to convince that the project has not suffered?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/1282/34), is one that is new.  I did a Google search and didn't find a lot of information on the subject.  I find it interesting and applicable to project management.

**Advantage:** Not a lot of information comes up on Google about the topic, so it would make a unique blog article.

**Disadvantage:** There may not be a lot of information on Google for the opposite reason, others don't find it important or interesting.

Answer (score 2):

I find the topic of [Stealth Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/1108/is-it-still-possible-to-use-formal-methods-if-the-organization-has-chosen-not-to/1112#1112) quite fascinating as it relates to instituting changes in an organization.

Many people resist change, and people oftentimes ask questions about how to institute change X in a company.  The principles of Stealth Project Management could be used to help institute a wide variety of changes and further demonstrates that you don't need a title to be a leader, and you don't need a title to make things happen!

**Advantage**: This is interesting, and the principles can be applied to other topics on our site.  Even though people have already written about Stealth Project Management, there may still be ways to give a story an interesting twist by solving another problem using the concepts.