# Who are The Notable Bloggers in the PM Community, and How Can We Get Them Involved in Our Site?

Tags: discussion, promotion, blogging

In this question, [What Are Some Interesting Questions That Could Be Used in a Blog Article To Help Promote The Site?](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144/what-are-some-interesting-questions-that-could-be-used-in-a-blog-article-to-help), we're compiling a list of interesting questions that could be potential blog topics to help promote the site.

I am a blogger, but I'll be completely honest with you.  I am a terrible blogger!  For years, mine has gone virtually unnoticed.  However, there are many people in the community who manage very active, productive blogs.  These individuals have a lot of referral power.

If you're a blogger, or if you know a blogger, who may be interested in picking one of our most interesting questions, blogging about the topic, and then referring the readers to our site, please list them below.

Answer (score 5):

A few ideas:

1. Invite notable bloggers to weigh in on 'best of' interesting PM questions. "We're not sure how to answer {question link}, do you have any advice?"
2. Ask PM questions on their behalf. If they write a blog entry or ask something (on their blog, twitter, or facebook) that contains a question -- actual or implied -- post it as a question here. Wait and see what kind of response it gets, then bring it to their attention. "I thought you brought up a really interesting question, and it got some interesting answers here {question link}."

I think it's important to only ping notable folks when you have something of direct interest to them.

Comment: +1 - Great advice on pinging notable people only with something very interesting.  Thank you!

Comment: Definitely a very effective way to get their attention.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert, and I'm not a project manager either, but one PM blog I do read (and enjoy) is [randsinrepose](http://www.randsinrepose.com) ([Michael Lopp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rands)).

(That aside, Google sent me [here](http://www.odesk.com/blog/2009/05/top-25-project-management-blogs/), but I can't vouch for any of them)

Comment: @Bengol - Awesome!  I'll check these out and see if we can elicit some good questions.

Answer (score 0):

One that I read from time to time is [Bruce Webster's](http://brucefwebster.com/) blog.