# How to Build Long Term Growth On the Site

Tags: discussion, site-survival

**UPDATE:**  Let's set a goal to have 10 awarded Announcer, Booster, or Publicist Badges.  If you have the Announcer badge, then go for the Booster badge and we'll count that as 2!  By May 15th, let's have any combination of 10 awards of these badges.  Right now, there are 2 Announcer badges that have been awarded.

---

The [Announcer, Booster, and Publicist Badges](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/) will not only add to your list of badges, but also sustain the site for years.

***So far, as of the time of this writing, [only two users have earned the Announcer badge](https://pm.stackexchange.com/badges/54/announcer).***

Take a moment to think about what these badges mean for this site's long-term growth.  For starters, here is the list and the requirements to earn each badge, in sequence:

[image: Announcer Badge]Shared a link to a question that was visited by 25 unique IP addresses in 3 days
[image: Booster Badge] Shared a link to a question that was visited by 300 unique IP addresses in 4 days
[image: Publicist Badge] Shared a link to a question that was visited by 1,000 unique IP addresses in 5 days

In order for me to build up enough traffic on [this question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/452/how-to-avoid-micro-managing-a-software-development-team) to drive just 25 unique IP addresses in 3 days, enough for the bronze Announcer badge, how many times do I need to share the same link on different sites?

If I get 3 unique IP addresses per day for every link I share, then that means that I have to share my link on almost *9 different sites*.  Let's say it takes me 18 days to get to this point.  That means that before I even brought in enough traffic to get the Announcer badge, I brought in a total of *270 unique IP addresses* before I had enough traffic built up to get 25 unique IP addresses in 3 days.

Even after earning the badge, these links are *still* funneling traffic into our site.

The important thing to consider is the total number of referring unique IP addresses that were counted before building up enough to meet the goals, as well as the number of IP addresses that continue to be counted after you've earned the badge.

If you've earned even just the Announcer badge, you've truly made an impact on building this site by opening up different, sustainable pipelines that will continue to drive traffic to this site.  A little bit of effort will go a long way!  If you stop sharing links, the work you've done here will continue to benefit the site.

Think about the number of StackOverflow questions that programmers stumble upon everyday.  Some of those questions are three years old, and they are *still* driving traffic to the site.  The people who asked and answered those questions have long forgotten about them, yet they persist!

Now, imagine the amount of traffic you'll need to build up and lead to this site in order to earn the Booster and Publicist badges!  How many unique IP's will those badge-earners drive to the site, not just in 4 or 5 days, but in 3 months, 6 months, or a year?

Focus on the inputs that will produce perpetual, long term results.  Let's focus on doing the types of things that will sustain long after we get distracted by other things that life will inevitably throw our way.

Comment: well said! we can add the featured tag (to be used in moderation please..) that will bump this to the meta sidebar on the main site for 30 days.

Comment: Unfortunately, some of us just don't have that kind of outreach. I have a very small reach in terms of project managers and PM sites, so my energies are best focused elsewhere -- perhaps on individuals. One thing is for sure: we won't say the site went down for lack of trying to make it work!

Comment: @ashes999 - I'll be the first to tell you that I'm a horrible blogger. Mine is a ghost town. I earned the Announcer badge by doing Google searches with the "last 24 hours" option to look for posts about my topic, where I could then add my 2 cents and post a link back to our site. Also, you've contributed a lot to this site already with your great questions and answers. I don't mean for this post to suggest that people aren't helping. Quite the contrary! However, we should make it a goal of having 10 users with the Announcer, Booster, or Publicist badge by May 10th!  We only need 8 more! :)

Answer (score 1):

You know, there is one untapped goldmine that we haven't hit yet. Cornelius Fitchner, author of the PM podcast, PDU podcast, and various other (in my opinion: awesome) PMP-related resources.

If we can get *him* to buy into it, he has quite a reach with his PMP-related products; I'm sure if he saw the benefit and usefulness of the site, he would be more than happy to tell others about it.

As far as I know, he's on various forums, etc. too.

Comment: Unfortunately our site has very little to do with PMP/PMBOK

Comment: @yegor256 I disagree. My reputation proves it -- software development and also primarily a PMP. Besides, PMPs can use this site to keep their credential current -- did you read my post in meta.pmse about it? And besides, it's a great resource for PMs -- PMP, Prince2, or otherwise.

Comment: Cornelius has re-tweeted posts I've made about the site.

Comment: @Mark great job! How did you pull that off?

Comment: I've been a guest on his podcasts.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to announce that we have 3 more users on this site who have earned the Announcer badge:

[image: Announcer Badge] Awarded May 3rd to [ciacibai](https://pm.stackexchange.com/users/1126/ciaocibai)
[image: Announcer Badge] Awarded May 4th to [Ryan Martens](https://pm.stackexchange.com/users/640/ryan-martens)
[image: Announcer Badge] Awarded May 1th to [Jean Tabaka](https://pm.stackexchange.com/users/1117/jean-tabaka)

The users awarded this badge have shared links to questions on this site that have helped drive organic growth and interest in this site, which increases our visits from search engines and drives this site closer to public launch.

The next site-building badge these users will aim for is the Silver Booster badge:

[image: Booster Badge] [About the Booster Badge](https://pm.stackexchange.com/badges/55/booster)

Thank you for helping to promote this site and moving us towards the goal of 10 Announcer, Booster, or Publicist badges by May 15th.  We need 4 more to meet our goal.

Answer (score 0):

For the question, [Scrum, Agile, Kanban looking for 'for dummies' type of information](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/1847/scrum-agile-kanban-looking-for-for-dummies-type-of-information), user [Perry Wilson](https://pm.stackexchange.com/users/131/perry-wilson) has earned the `Announcer` badge for sharing a link to a question that was visited by 25 IP addresses in 3 days!

[image: Bronze Announcer Badge]

Now that this link is out there in the world, it will continue to serve as an inbound tunnel, directing new Stack Exchange users and PM experts and enthusiasts to this site!

The next challenging badge for Perry Wilson to focus on is the silver `Booster` badge, which is earned by posting a link that is visited by 300 unique IP addresses in 4 days.

So far, no users have earned the `Booster` or Gold `Publicist` badges, and these badges must be earned in order, with the `Announcer` badge coming first, by posting links and getting unique visits on different questions.

Thank you, Perry Wilson, for your contributions to growing this site!  For more information on these site-growing badges, please see [this meta post](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/175/34).

We need 7 more of any of these badges to meet our goal of 10 Publicist, Booster, and Announcer badges by May 15th.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pleased to add [Mark Phillips](https://pm.stackexchange.com/users/14/mark-phillips) to the list of Bronze Announcer badge earners!

Mark has done a great job of tweeting questions and spreading word of our site, including acting as our spokesperson at the RallyOn 2011 Conference last week.

We now have a total of 7 Announcer Badges! Our goal was to get 10 by May 15th.

As a result of the efforts by the people who have helped spread the word on this site, our search engine traffic has more than doubled what it was 4 to 6 weeks ago!

Let's continue pushing forward by sharing more links to interesting questions, award more Announcer badges, and also target the Silver Booster badges!